# cannot initialize the type

Tags: java, tree, initialization

I build a class 'AbstractTree' and create another class 'SearchTree' which extends 'AbstractTree'.

```
public class SearchTree<TreeNode> extends AbstractTree<TreeNode> {
TreeNode root;
public SearchTree(){
    root=new TreeNode();
}
}
```

There is an error occured in the constructing method. It says that it cannot initialize the type TreeNode.

TreeNode is another class I build.

```
public class TreeNode<E> extends AbstractNode<E> {
E element;
TreeNode<E> parent;
ArrayList<TreeNode<E>> children;

public TreeNode(){
    parent=new TreeNode<E>();
    children=new ArrayList<TreeNode<E>>();
}
//...some other methods
}
```

Comment: No, `TreeNode` is a generic type variable.

Comment: Please post `AbstractTree` class code.

Comment: In the SearchTree class, when creating "root", I believe you need to provide it with a datatype for <E>. I believe that is what @SotiriosDelimanolis was getting at.

Comment: but shouldn't that issue only a warning?

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of SearchTree has an error. In fact `public class SearchTree<TreeNode> extends AbstractTree<TreeNode> {`is using TreeNode as a generic class Type parameter and not as the TreeNode class that you are intending to use here.

And so the generic type parameter that you called TreeNode is now hidding usage of the real TreeNode class. See attached image

[image: generic type hidding class]

Therefore I would change your SearchTree class the following way:

```
public class SearchTree<E> extends AbstractTree<TreeNode<E>>  {

    TreeNode<E> root;
    public SearchTree()
    {
        root = new TreeNode<E>();
    }

}
```